# Detect Incorrect stack variable usage

Tags: c++, memory-management, windbg

My application gives certain works to the worker agency to execute in a thread pool thread as given below

```
void Execute ProcessWork
{
    int nRes = 0;
    CFireProcessMessageWork *pProcessMessageWork = new CFireProcessMessageWork();
    // Incorrect use of stack variable
    pProcessMessageWork->m_pStatus = &nRes;
    // Worker Agency
    m_pMessageWorkerAgency->SubmitWork(pProcessMessageWork);
}
```

The definition of CFireProcessMessageWork is given below. The DoWork method of the class given below will be executed in a worker thread. Since the variable nRes is used in an improper way, my application crashes occasionally. I spent almost a week to identify the cause of the issue. I tried page heap with full options and Stack Frames (/RTCs) to detect the issue. But the application crashed at a location which has no relationship with the issue.

***Is there any tools microsoft provides to detect these kind of issues?***

```
class CFireProcessMessageWork
{
public:
    int *m_pStatus;
public:
    CFireProcessMessageWork()
    {
        m_pStatus = NULL;
    }
    int DoWork()
    {
     // Using Address of nRes
        *mpStatus = 0;
        // Do Some Work and Pass mpStatus to fill the error code
        HRESULT hRes = pGEMMessageEvents->ProcessMessage(varData, m_nMsgCount, m_newTkt,m_idxFunc,&m_nRetVal);
        return *mpStatus
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about a tool, but you should definitely have a *process* in place - it's called a *code-review*!

Comment: Why store an address in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that each one of those lines makes sense to the compiler. There is nothing *wrong* with them, and just the combination is not really good. Even then, it would require a good amount of extra work and analysis to determine that it is a wrong use.

Consider for example, that you could be joining the worker thread in the same function, and then everything would be correct, if the function did not process in a different thread but just manipulated the code in the `SubmitWork` call, then it would be correct... and the compiler does not necessarily know about *threads*, so the fact is that it is almost impossible for the compiler to detect this.

On the other hand, this is something that should be quite obvious to a reviewer, so it can be better tackled by reviewing code. Other possible options would be using some form of shared ownership to handle the resources --which might imply more cost:

```
void Execute ProcessWork {
    std::shared_ptr<int> nRes = std::make_shared<int>( 0 );
    CFireProcessMessageWork *pProcessMessageWork = new CFireProcessMessageWork();
    pProcessMessageWork->m_pStatus = nRes;                   // copies the shared_ptr
        m_pMessageWorkerAgency->SubmitWork(pProcessMessageWork);
}
```

In this case, the *shared* ownership of the object at the cost of an extra allocation, guarantees that the thread will not cause undefined behavior while updating the state. But while this will make the program correct from a language point of view, it might still be undesired: the status will not be *readable* outside of the worker thread, as the only other reference is *outside* of the worker control.

Comment: Rodriguez - dribeas: You have my +1 for the very ellaborate explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

You are writing a syntactically valid code here by passing `&nRes`, however since it is a local varaible in stack and it is being accessed in some other thread, the address is not going to be valid, resulting in crash. I think a careful peer code review should help resolve such issues.